# how to properly see the errors of a flask application in production mode

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi

I have made a flask application at my local computer in the debugging mode and it runs all fine. But when it comes to production, the website gives me 500 or internal server error, which I have no idea what the bug is. I am fairly new to flask production and this has been stopping me from moving forward for quite a few days.

My questions are:
1> in my local development environment, one could always print things out. But how can I see those prints in the production stage?
2> Do I see them through Apache2 log? Where is Apache2 log?

For production, I actually followed the tutorials from pythonprogramming.net. Youtube link is here:

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZNL4Ku1UQg&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDc_owjTbIY4rbgXOFkUYOUB&index=2](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

To use a very simple example, if the code imports a package which wasn't installed, where can we see the errors?

Thanks in advance.

I've tried to use to use try ... except block for every flask function. Whenever there is an exception, it can be return to the front-end. But what about other errors?

Answer (score 0):

I found out:

1. Use logging module
2. Read apache2 log from `/var/log/apache2`